# how to loop through rows columns in excel VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops

**Hi, I am trying to create a macro that has a loop which copies a function down column 1 (VOL) and another function down column 2 (CAPACITY) for each Station. This is what I have so far:**

```
Sub TieOut()
    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 3
            Worksheets("TieOut").Cells(i, j).Value = "'=INDEX('ZaiNet Data'!$A$1:$H$39038,MATCH('INDEX-MATCH'!Z$7&TEXT('INDEX-MATCH'!$A9,"m/dd/yyyy"),'ZaiNet Data'!$C$1:$C$39038,0), 4)"
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

**The picture of what I WANT is below:** You can see that I have manually copied and pasted my two functions down each column. I just need a macro that can loop through it.

[image]

**The function I want to be looped down the VOL column for each Station is:**

```
=INDEX('ZaiNet Data'!$A$1:$H$39038,MATCH('INDEX-MATCH'!Z$7&TEXT('INDEX-MATCH'!$A438,"M/DD/YYYY"),'ZaiNet Data'!$C$1:$C$39038,0), 4)
```

**The function I want to be looped down the CAPACITY column for each Station is:**

```
=INDEX('ZaiNet Data'!$A$1:$H$39038,MATCH('INDEX-MATCH'!Z$7&TEXT('INDEX-MATCH'!$A438,"M/DD/YYYY"),'ZaiNet Data'!$C$1:$C$39038,0), 5)
```

Could someone please help? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

****How can I make the loop run automatically without having to manually enter the formula into the first two cells and click on macro?
Also how can I make the loop run through all the columns/rows? (horizontically)****

I included two screen shots to show what I mean. Below is my current code.
[image]

[image]

Thanks!

```
    Sub Loop3()
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

    Dim i  As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
        With Worksheets("Loop")
            i = 1
            Do Until .Cells(10, i).Value = "blank"
                For j = 1 To 10
                    .Cells(j, i).Formula = "=INDEX('ZAINET DATA'!$A$1:$H$39038,MATCH(Loop!E$7&TEXT(Loop!$A9,""M/D/YYYY""),'ZAINET DATA'!$C$1:$C$39038,0),4)"
                    .Cells(j, i + 1).Formula = "=INDEX('ZAINET DATA'!$A$1:$H$39038,MATCH(Loop!E$7&TEXT(Loop!$A9,""M/D/YYYY""),'ZAINET DATA'!$C$1:$C$39038,0),5)"
                Next j
                i = i + 2
            Loop
    End With

    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @Techgirl09, If you're still following this question, I know there's an easier way to do this. 2 Questions: Is the range that the formula's copied into always the same (i.e. can you make it a named range)? and Do you want this to trigger on sheet activation, or something else?

Comment: looks like kevin sent you an email while you are taking the screenshot, please make sure to reply to him

Answer (score 6):

Here is my sugestion:

```
Dim i As integer, j as integer

With Worksheets("TimeOut")
    i = 26
    Do Until .Cells(8, i).Value = ""
        For j = 9 to 100 ' I do not know how many rows you will need it.'
            .Cells(j, i).Formula = "YourVolFormulaHere"
            .Cells(j, i + 1).Formula = "YourCapFormulaHere"
        Next j

        i = i + 2
    Loop
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks - that copied and pasted my formula through the cells but in order for it to do that, I need to manually enter the formula into the first two cells and then click on macro. 

Is there any way to make it completely automatic? For example if my sheet is completely blank as in the third STATION, how can the formula automatically be populated throughout?

Comment: With justhe code here the formula is written on the formula property, it is not copied.  There is no need for you to write the formula in the first two cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Create A Macro with the following thing inside:

```
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
```

That particular macro will copy the current cell (place your cursor in the VOL cell you wish to copy) down one row and then copy the CAP cell also.

This is only a single loop so you can automate copying VOL and CAP of where your current active cell (where your cursor is) to down 1 row.

Just put it inside a For loop statement to do it x number of times.
like:

```
For i = 1 to 100 'Do this 100 times
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
Next i
```

Comment: THANKS! I got it working. 

Now I need the loop to run until my left side column (date range) is blank. 

I will see how I can do this - if anyone can input - would greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This one is similar to @Wilhelm's solution.  The loop automates based on a range created by evaluating the populated date column.  This was slapped together based strictly on the conversation here and screenshots.

Please note: This assumes that the headers will always be on the same row (row 8).  Changing the first row of data (moving the header up/down) will cause the range automation to break unless you edit the range block to take in the header row dynamically.  Other assumptions include that VOL and CAPACITY formula column headers are named "Vol" and "Cap" respectively.

```
Sub Loop3()

Dim dtCnt As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim frmlas() As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'The following code block sets up the formula output range
dtCnt = Sheets("Loop").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row              'lowest date column populated
endHead = Sheets("Loop").Range("XFD8").End(xlToLeft).Column         'right most header populated
Set rng = Sheets("Loop").Range(Cells(9, 2), Cells(dtCnt, endHead))  'assigns range for automation

ReDim frmlas(1)      'array assigned to formula strings
    'VOL column formula
frmlas(0) = "VOL FORMULA"
    'CAPACITY column formula
frmlas(1) = "CAP FORMULA"

For i = 1 To rng.Columns.count
If rng(0, i).Value = "Vol" Then         'checks for volume formula column
    For j = 1 To rng.Rows.count
        rng(j, i).Formula= frmlas(0)    'inserts volume formula
    Next j
ElseIf rng(0, i).Value = "Cap" Then     'checks for capacity formula column
    For j = 1 To rng.Rows.count
        rng(j, i).Formula = frmlas(1)   'inserts capacity formula
    Next j
End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the Range object's [AutoFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221841(office.11).aspx) [method](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/35/vba-in-excel/9/) for this:

```
rngSource.AutoFill Destination:=rngDest
```

Specify the Source range that contains the values or formulas you want to fill down, and the Destination range as the whole range that you want the cells filled to. The Destination range must include the Source range. You can fill across as well as down.

It works exactly the same way as it would if you manually "dragged" the cells at the corner with the mouse; [absolute and relative formulas](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/relative-and-absolute-formulas.php) work as expected.

Here's an example:

```
'Set some example values'
Range("A1").Value = "1"
Range("B1").Formula = "=NOW()"
Range("C1").Formula = "=B1+A1"

'AutoFill the values / formulas to row 20'
Range("A1:C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:C20")
```

Hope this helps.