# VBA Do Until string found, then exit step

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have a file that has date values as column headers, and the last column will always be labeled "Grand Total". I want a way to look through the column headers, (which are in cells D4:I4) and input formulas to be filled down later.

For example, if we check D4, and it does not contain "Grand Totals", then I need the below formulas input in Cells L4 and L5:

```
Range("L4").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=""Weekending ""&TEXT(RC[-8],""mm/dd/yyy"")&"" Compliant?"""
Range("L5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF((IF(RC17=""Duplicate"",SUMIF(C2,RC2,C[-8]),RC[-8]))<27,""Compliant"",
  IF((IF(RC17=""Duplicate"",SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-8]),RC[-8]))<30,""Approaching Limit"",
  ""Over""))"
```

Then it would go to cell E4, and if it does not contain "Grand Totals", then the formulas need to be input in cells M4 and M5... Once "Grand Totals" are found [at the top of the loop], I need to exit the loop (but not the sub).

I tried to piece together bits from code I found:

```
Dim GrTot As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("D4:I4")
GrTot = "Grand Total"

Range("D4").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> GrTot
```

But I didnt know where to go. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have since tried another method based on an example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128841/how-to-loop-through-rows-columns-in-excel-vba-macro). This is what I have currently:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
With Worksheets("Pivot")
x = 4
Do Until .Cells(4, x).Value = "Grand Total"
    For y = 12 To 16
        .Cells(4, y).Formula = "=""Weekending ""&TEXT(RC[-8],""mm/dd/yyy"")&"" 
          Compliant?"""
        .Cells(5, y).Formula = "=IF((IF(RC17=""Duplicate"",SUMIF(C2,RC2,C[-8]),
          RC[-8]))<27,""Compliant"",IF((IF(RC17=""Duplicate"",
          SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-8]),RC[-8]))
          <30,""Approaching Limit"",""Over""))"
    Next y
    x = x + 1
Loop
End With
End Sub
```

But this one doesn't exit correctly. It will loop through fine, writing the formulas as I requested, but it doesn't exit the loop when it reaches the "Grand Total" column. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want it to check each cell and fill in formulas if it doesn't contain "Grand Totals" or do you actually want to the loop to end when you find "Grand Totals"?

Comment: Your goal sounds simple. You should use `Const` for R1C1 formulas to make code more readable. You are looping from Row 4 to bottom of `UsedRange`? You can use `Do Until ActiveCell.Value = GrTot` but you may end up infinite loop! You need to be more clear.

Comment: D_Zab, I need both.... I need to check each cell, if it does not contain "Grand Totals" then it should fill in the formula, but the loop should end as soon as "Grand Totals" are found. I just don't really know how to loop through 3 ranges at once to execute these steps. So if D4 =/= "Grand Totals", then put a formula in L4 and L5, then if E4 =/= "Grand Totals", put the same formula in M4 and M5, and so on until "Grand Totals" are found, then exit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each cell in the range; if the cell does not have a value you can write whatever to the cell and then something to the offset. As soon as a grand total is found in your range the loop can exit and move to the next range.

```
For Each item In Range

    If item.Value = GrTot Then
    Exit For
    'Perform action on cell 
    item.Value = formula
    item.offset(0,1).Value = formula 
    item.offset(0,2).Value = formula

End If
```