# Enter row and column number with userform

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a userform and enter numbers of row and column in VBA. Then starting a selected cell, system will generate random integer numbers between 10-90 in this range. Could you help me about which code can I use?

Comment: use `FOR...NEXT` loop and  `RAND()` function, try write some code, rewrite you question if you need...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to loop through rows columns in excel VBA Macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128841/how-to-loop-through-rows-columns-in-excel-vba-macro)

Answer (score 0):

May be you should start learning VBA in Excel from Microsoft msdn official websites: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192538(v=office.11).aspx ?

Comment: Just a personal suggestion, try not to be aggressive in your answers. The Internet has plenty of combatitive people, it doesn't need any more. Regardless of how little research they have done, people ask questions here to learn. Helping them learn makes all of our lives that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

In a less direct and more professional tone, you should start off by going into Visual Basic for Applications in your Excel Application. From there, you can right-click the `"Microsoft Excel Objects"` section and select `Insert -> UserForm`. From there, choose the "Toolbox" option in your Commands Toolbar. You can click Commands from your Toolbox and click inside the UserForm to create them. For this particular situation, I suggest using two TextBoxes and a Button.

You will then need to program the `Textbox.Text` values to be assigned to `Range`s, then have your Button do a `Sub Button_Click()` to generate a random number between 10 and 90.

Also, for future questions, I would look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to receive better assistance here at StackOverflow.

If you attempt to solve this puzzle on your own, feel free to update this question with your code and I will update my answer with a potential solution to the issue.